# Why do we need linkers if we have preprocessors?

Tags: c, linker

I know that a preprocessor replaces every preprocessor directive with the specified text in the preprocessing step. Then, if we have a function included in a library and we include that library and call that function, everything should work even without the linking step? Then, why do we need a linker?

Comment: Binary executables aren't made of text but of machine code.

Comment: You're mistaken. They (preprocessors & linkers) do different jobs and involved at different stages in the compilation process. Read about each and it'll become clear.

Comment: Because a library consists of a text file (the header that you #include) and a binary file (the precompiled machine code). The preprocessor uses the text file. The linker uses the binary file. Now, you *could* put all of the source code for the library in the header file, but that would just waste a bunch of compile time recompiling the same old thing. It would also create havoc (multiple definitions of the functions in the library) since header files are often included in multiple source files. In short, the #include file is not the library. The binary file that the linker uses is the library

Comment: Thank you very much, it made everything clear with the exception of this: So an #include file is not a library, but a header, right? I have always called #include files as libraries and I have treated headers as a synonym for libraries. I was wrong, right?

Comment: Right, you #include a header file, and you link a library. The header file typically has function declarations, #defines for constants that the functions use,  structure declarations, and typedefs. It may have other stuff as well. What it doesn't have is the code, that's in the library file. It may help to take a look at some system header files like `stdio.h` and `string.h` to see what's inside. Just be sure not to change anything :)

Comment: Do you have to, do you have to, do you have to have a linker?

Answer (score 2):

**Preprocessing happens first:**

Broadly speaking, it only replaces preprocessor ("#") symbols with whatever you've defined them to be.

---

**Compilation happens second:**

This step is executed separately for each source file, which means that it does not include the resolution of any function-call to a function which resides in a different source file (see below what 'resolution' means).

The result of this step is a set of object (compiled source code) files, one per each source file.

---

**Linkage happens third:**

This step is executed on the set of object files generated in the previous step.

At this point, each call from one object file to a function which resides in another object file, can be resolved, i.e., translated to a jump to the address of that function within the executable image.

The result of this step is either an executable file (if you've implemented the `main` entry point), or a library file (if you haven't).

---

Again - all of the above is a *Very Broadly Speaking* kind of description.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit fuzzy ... Linking is a mandatory step in compilation. The compiler generate an object file from every source file (excepted headers) in your project and the linker will stitches them into a single executable or shared library. Even without including a library, you need a linker. Read the Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing) .